# Why does my ESP8266 making an HTTP request to an MDNS responder keep getting redirected to my ISP's search engine?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, http

I have two ESP8266's trying to talk to each other, a 'host' and a 'client', if you will. I have the `ESP8266mDNS.h` responder running on the host at `esp8266wifi.local`. On sending an http GET request to  `http://esp8266wifi.local/`, I have the webserver send a simple "Success" message.

When I use my computer to access the host in a web browser, it responds just fine, "Success". But when I use the client ESP8266 to send the GET request, it appears to be redirected to my ISP's search engine. The raw html reads:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://search.frontier.com/search/?q=http://esp8266wifi.local/&t=0"/></head><body><script>window.location="http://search.frontier.com/search/?q="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&t=0";</script></body></html>
```

It appears to respond correctly when I connect to the IP address, `http://192.168.0.10/` using `ESP8266WebServer.h` but when I use the mDNS request I get redirected. Is there any way to work around this?

EDIT:

I tested on my phone's internet browser and my Wii U console and I also get the same redirect to my ISP's search engine.

Comment: Those devices probably don't support mDNS, so they do a regular DNS lookup to the ISP's DNS servers. Because that domain name doesn't exist outside of your network, ISP points it to their search engine.